# How can I use a bower component in Dart?

Tags: dart, polymer, bower, web-component

I have found a nice JS component that's installed with Bower.

I'd like to know how I could import my component and let it be served by Pub.

So far I've tried to `bower install` it, and it gets downloaded in the root of my project in `/bower_components`

And then in my `index.html` I tried:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-date-picker/paper-date-picker.html">
```

but Pub won't load the files (seems like it can't figure out relative paths in Bower).

Comment: can you post your folder structure? looks like your path might be wrong

Comment: I have /web and /bower_components at the root. index.html is in /web

Comment: I have not been able to import 3rd party polymer components base on javascript, because they depend on polymer.js and that conflict with polymer.dart. would you mind sharing how you did it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, pub serves web as root folder,  so you cant go deeper than root.
The easiest way to get this to work is to symlink bower_components folder into web folder, like pub does for packages folder.

Don't forget to remove `..` before `/bower_components` in your href attribute after that.

Answer (score 0):

Your path looks right `../` this is correct but go to `/bower_components/paper-date-picker/paper-date-picker.html` and make sure it is right.

or change that line to
`../bower_components/paper-date-picker/paper-date-picker-dialog.html`

and see if it works.